# Optimize regex for PHP method completion

Tags: php, regex

I am working on a regular expression for triggering php syntax method completion for deoplete in vim. There are two types of methods that need to be completed static methods with the double colon (::) and instance methods with the arrow (->).

[my] Rules for instance methods

- Dollar sign
- Followed by first character (Of the object name) is an alpha character or underscore
- Any characters after the first one are alpha numeric or underscore
- Arrow indicates beginning of method name and can appear right after the object name or on the next line

Regex for instance methods

```
\$\([a-zA-Z_][a-zA-Z0-9_]*\)\v?\h?\->
```

[my] Rules for static methods

- Must start with a capital alpha character
- Any characters after the first one are alpha numeric or underscore, alternatively the whole word could be (self, parent, or static)
- Double colon indicates the beginning of the method name

Regex static methods

```
\(self|parent|static|[A-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_]*\)::
```

The question is can I make this faster by doing some lookahead magic or something of that sort especially the static method regex?

Test text

```
// Should match
$this
    ->
// Should match
$someObject->
// Should not match
"somethingInAString->"
// Should not match
stdClass::
// Should match
SomeClass::
// Should match
parent::
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a tiny optimisation you can make by combining the first letter of the two words beginning with `s`, like

```
(s(elf|tatic)|parent|[A-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_]*)::
```

but in reality that will be a minuscule difference in speed, but a larger difference in readability, so I wouldn't advise it.

The real question is whether your regexes are getting optimised and compiled by deoplete. I've had a quick scan of the source and it wasn't apparent to me whether this is the case.

If you'll allow me to go off on one,....
Generally the advantages of regexes (particularly deterministic ones) is that they can be implemented *without* lookhead by turning them into a finite state automaton [read more somewhere like this](https://swtch.com/~rsc/regexp/regexp1.html); you process the input a character at the time, and make a transition to another state, with zero backtracking. If this method is used, it's very very fast anyway, and the hand-optimisations you could do would have been done in the stage of making the non-deterministic finite state automaton into a deterministic one.

Comment: Interesting, I haven't heard of this. So I really should not be looking to optimize my regex for method/function completion in vim? Should I ask the creator if it is necessary to hand optimize regex for Deoplete?

Comment: @Mike I don't mean you shouldn't, I mean it would save only a tiny amount, and would make it less clear. The time saving isn't enough to justify the clarity saving. Yes, it's worth asking the creator, but whether or not they're auto-optimising it for you, the hand optimisation is still of very slight benefit.

Comment: I asked the creator of the Deoplete library and he recomended against optimizing input_source, rather optimize the completion source. Thank you for your response anywho.

Comment: @Mike Well done for getting an answer from the author!

Answer (score 1):

that regex could not take more than a few tens of ms. In the use case of completion that would never be your bottleneck. A few ways to improve the performance of vim regexes anyway:

`\@>` which is a possessive multi
`\{-}` which is the non greedy version of `*`

Also interesting side-note, Russ Cox, who wrote this article https://swtch.com/~rsc/regexp/regexp1.html , helped in making vim's regex engine https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/vim_dev/o-oDH91G8NI